# Promises basics. How to promisify async node code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I am getting started with promises and trying to use them instead of callbacks to avoid a callback hell. The async functions are a mix of functions from MongoDB, Redis, bcrypt module, etc. I was able to get this far:

```
var insert = Q.denodify(db.collection(USERS).insert);
var createCollection = Q.denodify(db.createCollection);
var sadd = Q.denodify(redisClient.sadd);
var sismember = Q.denodify(redisClient.sismember);
var genSalt = Q.denodify(bcrypt.genSalt);
var hash = Q.denodify(bcrypt.hash);

// SANITY CHECK
// a "name" parameter is required
if(!req.body.name || !isValidName(req.body.name)) 
    return next(get400InvalidNameError());

// SANITY CHECK
// a "key" is optional
// if one is supplied, it must be valid
// this key will be hashed later
if(req.body.key){
    if(!isValidKey(req.body.key))
        return next(get400InvalidKeyError());
}

// STEPS:
// 1. 
// check Redis cache to see if the "name" is already taken
// if yes, return error. if no, continue
// 2. 
// construct a "user" object with name = req.body.name
// 3. 
// req.body.key provided?
// if yes, generate salt and hash the key. Set user.key = hash
// if not, continue
// 4.
// create a collection in MongoDB with the same name as req.body.name
// 5.
// add req.body.name to cache
// 6. 
// send a response to user using res.json() / res.end()
sismember(USERS,req.body.name)
.then(createUserObj,errHandler)
.then(genSalt(10),errHandler)
.then(hash(req.body.key,salt))
.then(createCollection(req.body.name),errHandler)
.then(sadd(USERS,req.body.name),errHandler)
.then(insert(user),errHandler)
.then(get200UserCreated,errHandler)
```

What confuses me is the last part where all of these functions are `then()`-ed together. I have a few questions:
1. How can the result of one async function be made available to another?
2. How can I conditionally decide which functions get executed? For example, I want to generate salt and hash only when `req.body.key` is provided.
3. Is my `then()` sequence proper?

Comment: `1.` this is how work a promise the result of a resolved promise become the argument of the next then

Comment: Answers to questions 1 and 2 can be found easily on StackOverflow if you take a moment to look. As for 3, no, because you're calling the functions immediately when defining the `then` argument instead of defining a function that will be called later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. How can the result of one async function be made available to another?

when you use Promise you can resolve or reject it.

```
var myprom = Promise.resolve(1) // the simplest promise way
```

Here if we chain with a `then` the argument will be equal to 1.

```
myprom.then(function( val ){
    
    console.log(val); // 1
    return 33;

}).then(function(passed){
    
    console.log(passed) // 33
    return 44;

}).then(function(other){
    
    console.log(other) // 44
    if( other > 44 ){
        return 'AAA';
    } else {
        return 'BBB';
    }
}).then(function(res){
    
    console.log(res) // BBB
    
})
```

here the ***important*** thing is that you `return` something from your promise.
Now the async. part :

```
// we can also instanciate a new Promise object
var myprom = new Promise(function(resolve , reject){
   
   console.log('we start here');
   
   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log('we continue here');
       resolve( 'time out' );
   } , 2000);

}).then(function( val ){ 
    console.log('and we end here : ' + val);
});
```

The second part `then` is invoked by the call of `resolve` in the first part.
So we always wait until the end, it's the "magic" of promise.

The argument passed to resolve become the argument of the next `then`.
It is the same as our first example about the `return` it is very **important**

When you do :

```
 sismember(USERS,req.body.name)
```

it is the same principle that the timeout.

```
 var sismember = function(USERS , req.body.name){
     var promiseToReturn = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
         var result = ''; // <---do something with USERS and req.body.name
         
         // and if it is ok 
           if(result){
            resolve( result )
           } else {// if it is not ok 
            reject( result )
           }

     });
     return promiseToReturn; // <-- we can chain with then
 })
 .then(createUserObj,errHandler)
```

The next then (after sismember) will invoke `createUserObj` with `result` as argument.
It become :

```
 var sismember = function(USERS , req.body.name){
     var promiseToReturn = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
         var result = ''; // <---do something with USERS and req.body.name
         
         // and if it is ok 
           if(result){
            resolve( result )
           } else {// if it is not ok 
            reject( result )
           }

     });
     return promiseToReturn; // <-- we can chain with then
 })
 .then(function createUserObj( resultOfsismember){
      var createdUser = {} //<--- do what you want with the resultOfsismember
      // and return something to be handled by next then.
     if(everyThingIsOk){ 
       return createdUser;
     } else {
       return Promise.reject( 'error during creation');
       // this will be handled by next then error handler or catch
     }
 } , errHandler ); //<--- you provide here an error handler for  sismember
```

> 2. How can I conditionally decide which functions get executed? For example, I want to generate salt and hash only when req.body.key is provided.

Different way to do that.

> 3. Is my then() sequence proper?

**No !**

you can't call a function like you do.

```
.then(genSalt(10),errHandler) // <-- you are invoking the result not the function
// you are doing something like that:
.then('Adekj34LLKDF' , errHandler)
```

if you want to add an argument use the `bind`

```
 .then(genSalt.bind(null , 10), errHandler)
 // we invoke the genSalt in a null context with 10 as first argument
```

But the promise chain **provide the argument** from the prev function you don't have to provide it !
*see example above*

---

once you resolved this problem, add a catch at the end to handle any error that could occur.
this part :

```
.then(get200UserCreated,errHandler)//<--- errHandler for prev then
```

have an error handler but only for this part :

```
.then(insert(user),errHandler)
```

if you have an error during `insert(user)` it will be handled by the next then error handler or catch.

```
sismember(USERS,req.body.name)
.then(createUserObj,errHandler)// <-- errHandler for : sismember
.then(genSalt(10),errHandler)// <-- errHandler for : createUserObj
.then(hash(req.body.key,salt))// <-- missing errHandler for : genSalt
.then(createCollection(req.body.name),errHandler)// <-- errHandler for : hash
.then(sadd(USERS,req.body.name),errHandler)// <-- errHandler for createCollection
.then(insert(user),errHandler)// <-- errHandler for : 
.then(get200UserCreated,errHandler)// <-- errHandler for : insert
.catch(errHandler)// <-- errHandler for : get200UserCreated
```

i've wrote something about error handler [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33045163/2037556), you should take a look at that.